Performance PHP on Windows Server
I'have tried to execute this code in 2 windows server with IIS and PHP 8.2 (x64), but the performance is very different.
Server:

OLD (server 1) - Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T7700 @ 2.40GHz


Base speed:   2,99 GHz
Sockets:  1
Virtual processors:   2
Virtual machine:  Yes
Cache L1: N/D
RAM 6GB


NEW (server 2) - Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248R CPU @ 3.00GHz


Base speed:   2,99 GHz
Sockets:  1
Virtual processors:   4
Virtual machine:  Yes
L1 cache: N/A
RAM: 6GB

#region CPU
$cpu_req = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'c') ?? 2000000; //n req

$start_time = microtime(true);
// Encrypt and decrypt a string 50,000 times.
$encrypt_method = 'AES-256-CBC';
//pls set your unique hashing key
// hash
$key = hash('sha256', 'fkejfheiwht348tekjs');
// iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', '@Security2K21'), 0, 16);
$string = 'blabla';
$times_run = 0;
while ( $times_run < $cpu_req ) {
   $encrypted = openssl_encrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
   $decrypted = openssl_decrypt( $encrypted, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
   $times_run++;
}

$execution_time = (microtime(true) - $start_time);
echo "CPU Time: ".$execution_time." sec<br>";
#endregion

The response are:

Server 1: CPU Time: 4.0015439987183 sec
Server 2: CPU Time: 8.5996899604797 sec

I don't understand why server 2 (the new server) is significantly slower than server 1.
Could you help me to understand?
I have tried to execute PHP script more times

Do you find this performance difference with any PHP code, or only with the openssl functions?

any PHP code, all project is slow :(

Well, the number of virtual processors don't matter because a single PHP script always runs on a single processor. Nevertheless the Xeon is a much newer and better processor than the Core2 Duo. I can't see any other clue in your question that could explain this. There could be many reasons I can think of. I'm not sure listing them will help?

"Virtual machine: Yes" Does that mean PHP runs on a VM?

@Olivier: I think gatfil rents hosting space somewhere, and wants to compare the new service to the old one by running a PHP test script. So, yes, that would be a VM of some kind. This can indeed be relevant. You often simply get what you pay for, so knowing which exact hosting spaces we talk about here would be useful (company, package & price). This is all speculation, of course.

@KIKOSoftware both are virtual machine, I have tried with other "stress" test and I've find that test with "openssl functions" are very slow as compared to others test. in this moment I don't have information about hosting.

OpenSSL function rely on the OpenSSL DLLs in Windows, like libcrypto-3-x64.dll. These DLLs can come in many versions. My point is that testing OpenSSL functions may not be a good test of PHP performance as such. Try to use functions that are internal to PHP instead. This is basically the point I was trying to make with my first comment.

@KIKOSoftware I'm in trouble because I don't understand where and why the project became so slow on the new server, I started testing CPU, RAM and Disk, as the Mysql DB doesn't seem to have performance problems.
I tried to stress the CPU using the Fibonacci function, the new server is slower but I don't notice the same difference compared to the test with "openssl". Do you have any tests you could recommend to me to understand better?

Generating a Fibonacci series is a good PHP test. You didn't say how big, or small, the difference is with this test, but the two servers sound quite comparable, so I wouldn't think anything is wrong when they fall without about 15% of each other. I also have no idea what projects you're running, but most websites spend most of their time accessing databases. So a test that involves database access would be most indicative of the speed your users would experience. There are many things you can do to speed up database access.


You did not tell us whether the two Windows server OS are of the same version (or not) 2. Do you have other tasks performing on the server ? (apart from running the PHP) ? 3. What way did you use to deploy the PHP on the IIS ? Are the two servers using the same way to get PHP running ? 4. Any differences in IO between the two servers ? 5. Last , but not least - strictly speaking what you have posted is not a coding / programming question.


@KIKOSoftware Test Fibonacci I have this result: Server 1 (OLD) 17.20 sec and Server 2 (New) 18.24 sec con fibonacci(10);
Database working fine In my opinion, Do you have suggestion to improve speed to database access?

@KenLee 1. Server 1 Server 2012 R2 Standard, Server 2 Server 2022 Standard; 2. Server 1 in use, Server 2 (new) is unloaded; 3. I use PHP Manager to install ad manage PHP preference in IIS; 4. I don't know; 5. No I don't understand why my project in too slow in new server :(

I agree with Ken Lee that this isn't a coding question. You're asking us to guess based on minimal, and sometimes contradictory, information. "Any php code is slow", when it really is within 10% of each other. "Database working fine", and then ask for advice how to improve the speed. This isn't getting us anywhere. I sympathize with your problem, which does indeed seem to exist, but this isn't coding.

Use Windows Performance Monitor to track CPU performance counters.
